# how to Launch android application through munkeyrunner by pythonscript

Tags: android, python, python-3.x, automated-tests

I want to launch an Android application through Monkey runner API using Python script,
what will be the method for it? Thanks in advance

Comment: any other method which will open an application with Application Name not package name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With [`startActivity`](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/MonkeyDevice.html#startActivity) -- such as:

```
device.startActivity( "", "android.settings.APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS", "<package name>" );
```

brings up the Application Detail for whichever package you like. Similarly, you can launch any activity by package name, and activity name.